# I have Canadian passport, can I obtain a Canadian visa for my Saudi passport?

Tags: visas, canada, canadian-citizens, dual-nationality, saudi-citizens

I have a saudi and a canadian passport. I am planning to do my masters in Vancouver but I want to enter Canada as a Saudi because I am entitled for a scholarship from Saudi and it requires that I must have the visa of the country I am willing to study at on my Saudi passport.

Is it legal for me to apply for a Canadian visa if I have the Canadian passport?
Is it legal to live in Canada as a foreigner while I am already Canadian?

Comment: Talk to the Saudi organization who gives the scholarship. Maybe they only require you to have all *necessary* visas to conduct your studies, which in your case means no visas are needed.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe it is possible for a Canadian citizen to get a Canadian visa.

You can enter and leave Canada on any passport you want, but a Saudi passport does not have visa-free access to Canada, so that wouldn't work either.